# GLSL for Minecraft: How I set a position for clouds?

Tags: glsl, minecraft

I'm using `gl_FragCoord.xy`, but the clouds are locked to the player eye or camera position. So they are moving with you, if you look back. But I want the clouds to have they own static position. I tried it with `worldposition = gbufferModelViewInverse * fragposition` but with a ugly result. The clouds are stretching if I looked to the sunrise or sunset and had a mirror effect. So they had the same sample like at sunrise if I looks at the sunset.

Now my question: How can I make it so that if the player look at left, that the clouds are not moving with the player eye? It's hard to explain it, so I tried to create a simple Picture:

[image: Example image]

Here is a part from my code:

```
float hash( float n )
{
    return fract(sin(n)*43758.5453);
}

float noise( in vec2 x )
{
    vec2 p = floor(x);
    vec2 f = fract(x);
        f = f*f*(3.0-2.0*f);
        float n = p.x + p.y*57.0;
        float res = mix(mix( hash(n+  0.0), hash(n+  1.0),f.x), mix( hash(n+ 57.0), hash(n+ 58.0),f.x),f.y);
        return res;
}

float fbm( vec2 p )
{
        float f = 0.0;
        f += 0.50000*noise( p ); p = p*2.02;
        f += 0.25000*noise( p ); p = p*2.03;
        f += 0.12500*noise( p ); p = p*2.01;
        f += 0.06250*noise( p ); p = p*2.04;
        f += 0.03125*noise( p );
        return f/0.984375;
}

#define CLOUD_COVER         0.55
#define CLOUD_SHARPNESS     0.015

// Wind - Used to animate the clouds
vec2 wind_vec = vec2(0.001 + frameTimeCounter*0.005, 0.003 + frameTimeCounter * 0.005);

// Set up domain
vec2 q = (gl_FragCoord.xy / 2024);
vec2 p = -1.0 + 3.0 * q + wind_vec;

// Create noise using fBm
float f = fbm( 4.0*p );

float cover = CLOUD_COVER;
float sharpness = CLOUD_SHARPNESS;

float c = f - (1.0 - cover);
if ( c < 0.0 )
c = 0.0;

f = 1.0 - (pow(sharpness, c));

color += f/15*TimeDay;
color += vec3(0.03, 0.19, 0.99)*f/1000*TimeMidnight;
```

Comment: Are you looking for a way to create a skybox?